# Code is running fine but corona simulator freezes at a particular scene

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have an app that keeps on freezing at the 9th scene. I'm currently using storyboard and the idea is to go to a scene when players answered a question. I used print statements to confirm that the corona has entered the 10th scene(all of the codes work and runs in scene10) but the simulator freezes at scene 9. I tried linking scene 9 to scene 1 which is also the same result, the simulator screen freezes at scene9 instead of going to scene1 but the print statements in scene 1 showed on the simulator. The codes work as I have print statements in every function. I took out some codes and changed the name of the files but no luck. What else can I look at?

I also ran the code on my phone and got some what seems to be some errors:

```
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962): Hardware: universal5410
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962): Revision: 10
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962): Bootloader: I9500ZSUCMK3
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962): Radio: unknown
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962): Kernel: Linux version 3.4.5-2138764 (se.infra@R0304-0
8) (gcc version 4.6.x-google 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri No
v 15 16:58:07 KST 2013
```

and then more crash detectors with a bunch of numbers behind it.

```
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962):     d0  65746172656e6567  d1  7571207478656e20
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  3ff0000000000000
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962):     d6  c00ffffe00000000  d7  c07ffff000000000
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962):     d8  40400030c07ffff0  d9  000000003f800000
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2962):     d10 000000003f7fffec  d11 0000000000000000
.....

E/android.os.Debug( 2962): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dump
state_app_error
I/dumpstate(29372): begin
I/dumpstate(29372): dumpstate is still running
....
```

What i could make out from this is that the app crashed and there seems to be something wrong with the storage problem?(I think thats what dumpstate refers to?)

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local widget = require "widget"
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local function returnHome()
storyboard.gotoScene("scene_menu", "crossFade",1000)

return true
end

local physics = require('physics')
physics.start()

-- Clear previous scene


-- local forward references should go here --
local score = 0
local scoreText
local scoreForLevelComplete
local background
local infoBar
local restartBtn
local cannon
local levelNum
local balloon = {}
local cannonCharge = {}
local ballCollision = {}
local shot = {}
local cannonBall
local impulse = 0
local balloons = {}
local cannonCharge = {}
local shot = {}
local cannonBalls = display.newGroup()
local pop = audio.loadSound('pop.mp3')
local wrongAnswer


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------




function scene:createScene( event )
local group = self.view
storyboard.removeAll()
print('purge scene')
  end

function scene:enterScene(event)
 local group = self.view

background = display.newImage( "bkg_clouds.png")
group:insert(background)
background.x = 230
background.y = 195

scoreText = display.newText( storyboard.state.score, 0, 0, native.systemFont, 32 )
scoreText:setFillColor( 0,0, 0 )
scoreText.x = 87
scoreText.y = 28
group:insert( scoreText ) 

questionText = display.newText('a', display.contentCenterX, display.contentWidth/4, native.systemFont, 40)
group:insert(questionText)

infoBar = display.newImage ("infoBar.png")
group:insert(infoBar)
infoBar.x = 10
infoBar.y = 25

restartBtn = widget.newButton{
defaultFile = "restartBtn.png",
onRelease = returnHome
}
restartBtn.x = 470
restartBtn.y = 300
group:insert(restartBtn)


cannon = display.newImage ("cannon.png")
group:insert(cannon)
cannon.x = 10
cannon.y = 270

cannon.anchorX = 0.5
cannon.anchorY = 0.5
restartBtn.isVisible = true

local MemoryLabel = display.newText( 
    { 
        text = '',
        x = 250,
        y = 220,
        font = 'Arial',
        fontSize = 32,
        align = "center"
    }
)
MemoryLabel:setFillColor( 0 )
group:insert(MemoryLabel)

local TextureLabel = display.newText( 
    { 
        text = '',
        x = 250,
        y = 200,
        font = 'Arial',
        fontSize = 32,
        align = "center"
    }
)
TextureLabel:setFillColor( 0 )
group:insert(TextureLabel)

-- To check available memory
function checkMemory()
    collectgarbage( "collect" )
    MemoryLabel.text = string.format( "M:%.2f KB", collectgarbage( "count" ) )
    TextureLabel.text = "T:"..(string.format( "%.2f KB", system.getInfo("textureMemoryUsed") / (1024 * 1024)) )

end

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, checkMemory, 0 )


local balloon1 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 70)
local balloon2 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 115)
local balloon3 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 160)

group:insert(balloon1)
group:insert(balloon2)
group:insert(balloon3)

physics.addBody(balloon1)
physics.addBody(balloon2)
physics.addBody(balloon3)

balloon1.bodyType = 'static'
balloon2.bodyType = 'static'
balloon3.bodyType = 'static'

table.insert(balloons, balloon1)      
table.insert(balloons, balloon2)      
table.insert(balloons, balloon3) 

local balloonText1 = display.newText('\227\129\130', 495, 70)
balloonText1:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
local balloonText2 = display.newText('\227\129\132', 495, 115)
balloonText2:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
local balloonText3 = display.newText('\227\129\134', 495, 160)
balloonText3:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )


group:insert(balloonText1)
group:insert(balloonText2)
group:insert(balloonText3)

function cannonCharge:touch(event)
  if(event.phase == 'began') then
        impulse = 0
        cannon.isVisible = true
        Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', charge)
        print ('cannonCharge')
    end
end

function shot:touch(event)
    if(event.phase == 'ended') then

        Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame', charge)
        cannon.isVisible = true
        cannon.rotation = 0

        cannonBall = display.newImage('cannon ball.png', 84, 220)
        physics.addBody(cannonBall, {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 0})
        group:insert(cannonBall)
        print ('shot')

-- Shoot cannon ball
cannonBall:applyLinearImpulse(3, impulse, cannonBall.x, cannonBall.y )

--Collision listener
print('event listener')
cannonBall:addEventListener ('collision', ballCollision)

    end
end

function charge()
local degreesPerFrame = 1
cannon.rotation = cannon.rotation - degreesPerFrame 
impulse=impulse-0.2

     if(cannon.rotation < -46) then
          cannon.rotation = -46
          impulse = -3.2
          print('Charge')
        end
end


function ballCollision(event)
   if (event.other == balloons[1])  then
        scene.updateScore()
        print('Ball is colliding')
        balloon1:removeSelf()
        balloon1 = nil
        balloonText1:removeSelf() 
        balloonText1 = nil
        local popSound = audio.play(pop)
        print('Before changing scene')
        storyboard.gotoScene("correct1", "fade", 3000)
  else
   if (event.other == balloons[2])  then
        print('Ball is colliding')
        balloon2:removeSelf()
        balloon2 = nil
        balloonText2:removeSelf() 
        balloonText2 = nil
        local popSound = audio.play(pop)
        print('Before changing scene')
        storyboard.gotoScene("wrong1", "fade", 3000)
  else
   if (event.other == balloons[3])  then
        print('Ball is colliding')
        balloon3:removeSelf()
        balloon3 = nil
        balloonText3:removeSelf() 
        balloonText3 = nil
        local popSound = audio.play(pop)
        print('Before changing scene')
        storyboard.gotoScene("wrong1", "fade", 3000)
    end
    end
    end
end

background:addEventListener('touch', cannonCharge)
background:addEventListener('touch', shot) 
end

function scene.updateScore()
  storyboard.state.score = storyboard.state.score + 50
  scoreText.text = storyboard.state.score
end

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:


function scene:exitScene(event)
local group = self.view

background:removeEventListener('touch', cannonCharge)
background:removeEventListener('touch', shot)


end

function scene:destroyScene(event)

audio.stop(popSound)
audio.dispose(pop)
popSound = nil
pop = nil
--cannonBall:removeEventListener ('collision', ballCollision)

if restartBtn then
restartBtn:removeSelf()
restartBtn = nil


end

end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("updateScore", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

So this goes to next scene which is

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local widget = require "widget"
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local function returnHome()
storyboard.gotoScene("scene_menu", "crossFade",1000)

return true
end

local physics = require('physics')
physics.start()

-- Clear previous scene
storyboard.removeAll()

-- local forward references should go here --

local scoreText
local background
local infoBar
local restartBtn
local cannon
local balloon = {}
local cannonCharge = {}
local ballCollision = {}
local shot = {}
local cannonBall
local impulse = 0
local balloons = {}
local cannonCharge = {}
local shot = {}
local cannonBalls = display.newGroup()
local pop = audio.loadSound('pop.mp3')
local wrongAnswer


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------




function scene:createScene( event )
local group = self.view
storyboard.removeAll()
print('purge scene')

  end

function scene:enterScene(event)
 local group = self.view

background = display.newImage( "bkg_clouds.png")
group:insert(background)
background.x = 230
background.y = 195

local cannon = display.newImage ("cannon.png")
group:insert(cannon)
cannon.x = 10
cannon.y = 270

scoreText = display.newText( storyboard.state.score, 0, 0, native.systemFont, 32 )
scoreText:setFillColor( 0,0, 0 )
scoreText.x = 87
scoreText.y = 28
group:insert( scoreText ) 

questionText = display.newText('i', display.contentCenterX, display.contentWidth/4, native.systemFont, 40)
group:insert(questionText)

infoBar = display.newImage ("infoBar.png")
group:insert(infoBar)
infoBar.x = 10
infoBar.y = 25

restartBtn = widget.newButton{
defaultFile = "restartBtn.png",
onRelease = returnHome
}
restartBtn.x = 470
restartBtn.y = 300
group:insert(restartBtn)


cannon = display.newImage ("cannon.png")
group:insert(cannon)
cannon.x = 10
cannon.y = 270

cannon.anchorX = 0.5
cannon.anchorY = 0.5
restartBtn.isVisible = true

local MemoryLabel = display.newText( 
    { 
        text = '',
        x = 250,
        y = 220,
        font = 'Arial',
        fontSize = 32,
        align = "center"
    }
)
MemoryLabel:setFillColor( 0 )
group:insert(MemoryLabel)

local TextureLabel = display.newText( 
    { 
        text = '',
        x = 250,
        y = 200,
        font = 'Arial',
        fontSize = 32,
        align = "center"
    }
)
TextureLabel:setFillColor( 0 )
group:insert(TextureLabel)

-- To check available memory
function checkMemory()
    collectgarbage( "collect" )
    MemoryLabel.text = string.format( "M:%.2f KB", collectgarbage( "count" ) )
    TextureLabel.text = "T:"..(string.format( "%.2f KB", system.getInfo("textureMemoryUsed") / (1024 * 1024)) )

end

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, checkMemory, 0 )

local balloon1 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 70)
local balloon2 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 115)
local balloon3 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 160)

group:insert(balloon1)
group:insert(balloon2)
group:insert(balloon3)

physics.addBody(balloon1)
physics.addBody(balloon2)
physics.addBody(balloon3)

balloon1.bodyType = 'static'
balloon2.bodyType = 'static'
balloon3.bodyType = 'static'

table.insert(balloons, balloon1)      
table.insert(balloons, balloon2)      
table.insert(balloons, balloon3) 

local balloonText1 = display.newText('\227\129\141', 495, 70)
balloonText1:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
local balloonText2 = display.newText('\227\129\138', 495, 115)
balloonText2:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
local balloonText3 = display.newText('\227\129\132', 495, 160)
balloonText3:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )


group:insert(balloonText1)
group:insert(balloonText2)
group:insert(balloonText3)

function cannonCharge:touch(event)
  if(event.phase == 'began') then
        impulse = 0
        cannon.isVisible = true
        Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', charge)
        print ('cannonCharge')
    end
end

function shot:touch(event)
    if(event.phase == 'ended') then

        Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame', charge)
        cannon.isVisible = true
        cannon.rotation = 0

        cannonBall = display.newImage('cannon ball.png', 84, 220)
        physics.addBody(cannonBall, {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 0})
        group:insert(cannonBall)
        print ('shot')

-- Shoot cannon ball
cannonBall:applyLinearImpulse(3, impulse, cannonBall.x, cannonBall.y )

--Collision listener
print('event listener')
cannonBall:addEventListener ('collision', ballCollision)

    end
end

function charge()
local degreesPerFrame = 1
cannon.rotation = cannon.rotation - degreesPerFrame 
impulse=impulse-0.2

     if(cannon.rotation < -46) then
          cannon.rotation = -46
          impulse = -3.2
          print('Charge')
        end
end


function ballCollision(event)
   if (event.other == balloons[1])  then
        print('Ball is colliding')
        balloon1:removeSelf()
        balloon1 = nil
        balloon2:removeSelf()
        balloon2 = nil
        balloon3:removeSelf()
        balloon3 = nil


        balloonText1:removeSelf() 
        balloonText1 = nil
        balloonText2:removeSelf() 
        balloonText2 = nil
        balloonText3:removeSelf() 
        balloonText3 = nil
        local popSound = audio.play(pop)
        storyboard.gotoScene("Question3", "fade", 1000)
  else
   if (event.other == balloons[2])  then
        print('Ball is colliding')
        balloon1:removeSelf()
        balloon1 = nil
        balloon2:removeSelf()
        balloon2 = nil
        balloon3:removeSelf()
        balloon3 = nil


        balloonText1:removeSelf() 
        balloonText1 = nil
        balloonText2:removeSelf() 
        balloonText2 = nil
        balloonText3:removeSelf() 
        balloonText3 = nil

        local popSound = audio.play(pop)
        storyboard.gotoScene("Question3", "fade", 1000)
  else
   if (event.other == balloons[3])  then
        scene.updateScore()
        print('Ball is colliding')
        balloon1:removeSelf()
        balloon1 = nil
        balloon2:removeSelf()
        balloon2 = nil
        balloon3:removeSelf()
        balloon3 = nil


        balloonText1:removeSelf() 
        balloonText1 = nil
        balloonText2:removeSelf() 
        balloonText2 = nil
        balloonText3:removeSelf() 
        balloonText3 = nil
        local popSound = audio.play(pop)
        storyboard.gotoScene("Question3", "fade", 1000)
    end
    end
    end
end

background:addEventListener('touch', cannonCharge)
background:addEventListener('touch', shot) 
end

function scene.updateScore()
  storyboard.state.score = storyboard.state.score + 50
  scoreText.text = storyboard.state.score
end

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:


function scene:exitScene(event)
local group = self.view

cannonBall:removeSelf()
cannonBall = nill

audio.stop(popSound)
audio.dispose(pop)
popSound = nil
pop = nil

background:removeEventListener('touch', cannonCharge)
background:removeEventListener('touch', shot)
physics.stop()
end

function scene:destroyScene(event)


if restartBtn then
restartBtn:removeSelf()
restartBtn = nil
end

end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("updateScore", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

Comment: Are you removing all objects created inside scene 9..?

Comment: Yes, i have a storyboard.removeAll() at the start of createScene for each code file, which I think removes the objects, modules etc.

Comment: There could be several reasons for this. If you setup your app so it goes from main to scene 10 to scene 9 to scene 1 (no other scenes in between), does it still freeze?

Comment: I did what you told and something weird happened. After the change, i run the code the first time and it worked, except the audio at scene 1 didn't work but it went from scene 1 to results scene. When i run it the second time, it doesn't work anymore and freezes at scene 1 screen on the simulator.

Comment: When i run scene1,2,3,4 and back to scene 1, the collision listener suddenly doesn't work, but it worked at the start, is there any particular reason that it would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to solve, but I will attempt an indirect answer.

Could you try adding a memory debug feature directly into corona like this one for example:

```
oMemoryLabel = display.newText( 
    { 
        text = '',
        x = display.contentWidth*0.33,
        y = display.contentHeiht*0.33,
        font = 'Arial',
        fontSize = 32,
        align = "center"
    }
)
oMemoryLabel:setFillColor( 0 )
oGroup:insert(oMemoryLabel)

oTextureLabel = display.newText( 
    { 
        text = '',
        x = display.contentWidth*0.66,
        y = display.contentHeiht*0.66,
        font = 'Arial',
        fontSize = 32,
        align = "center"
    }
)
oTextureLabel:setFillColor( 0 )
oGroup:insert(oTextureLabel)

-- To check available memory
function checkMemory()
    collectgarbage( "collect" )
    oMemoryLabel.text = string.format( "M:%.2f KB", collectgarbage( "count" ) )
    oTextureLabel.text = "T:"..(string.format( "%.2f KB", system.getInfo("textureMemoryUsed") / (1024 * 1024)) )
end

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, checkMemory, 0 )
```

2 ways to use this, either you load it only once as a stage layer on top of all others, so that it won't get unloaded between stages loading, OR you simple re-create this on every stage for now... It will still give you the right number.
If the memory usage OR texture usage keep increasing between scenes, bad news, you may have a leak or something doesn't get deleted properly (hence creating the weird crash in the end).
Good luck anyway :)

Cheers

Comment: I tested it and found that my memory usage increases by 1 or 2 for each scene. Is it normal that my memory usage starts out at 301.36kb?

Comment: I have a storyboard.removeAll() at the createScene for each of my code files, according to the site, removing the scene will completely unload the module." So i assume it frees the memory too?

Comment: If it keeps increasing between each scene then you must have a leak... Try to do scene 1 -> scene 2 -> 3 -> ... -> 10 -> 1 -> 2 for a while and see if it keeps constantly increasing. If it does then you have an issue in the code. It's hard without seeing your code though. One suggestion would be to only try with scene 1 -> scene 2 -> scene 1 -> etc and see if it also increases :) In this case you could narrow it down

Answer (score 0):

Removing scenes does not stop physics on the scene, nor does it stop any Runtime listeners.  Also timers, transitions, anything with a call back still runs until you stop them.  If the objects those events are tied to don't exist, you will get weird crashes.

Make sure you clean up your scene properly.